# Firefox doesn't calculate height of elements with negative margins (for overflow)

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar, overflow

When there are negative vertical margins, Firefox does not properly factor that into the height consideration when deciding whether elements are overflowing a container.

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/rdo8qrj2/

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">I have border-bottom:500px, and margin-bottom:-500px</div>  
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.child {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: solid 500px red;
    margin-bottom: -500px;
}
```

Chrome correctly subtracts from the child element's height, and does not scroll. Firefox does scroll. Is there a fix or a workaround for this?

Comment: I think Firefox does it right. What if I want to see the whole of the border? Also, clientHeight and offsetHeight are both 100, which is correct.

Comment: I don't particularly care who is "right"--I just care that it's consistent. If you think Firefox is right, then do you know a fix or workaround for Chrome?

Comment: > "What if I want to see the whole of the border?"

The issue is that the negative bottom margin actually should be pulling the bottom of the page flow up. In a normal situation, doing this would pull lower content up, and if z-indexes are higher, cover the content. In this case, I expect a negative bottom margin will pull up the point where the container will overflow and trigger a scroll.

Comment: A workaround for Chrome, no, I can't seem to get `parent` to scroll. Workaround for FF is easy: just set overflow to hidden.

Comment: Can't set overflow to hidden--it needs to scroll when content overflows.

Comment: And you can't get rid of the large border on the content?

Comment: It's there for a reason, yes.

Comment: How about we bring ie8 compared to ie9, or 10, consistencies are not part of web development  :)